# What's the default expansion policy in the variable expand case?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

What's the default expansion policy in the variable expand case when using Memgraph?

When I have a query `MATCH (x {id: 587})-[edge_list:Type *dfs..10]-(y {id: 963}) RETURN *;` I'm using `DFS` algorithm. I explicitly tell to use `DFS`.

Which algorithm is used if I omit `dsf`: `MATCH (x {id: 587})-[edge_list:Type *..10]-(y {id: 963}) RETURN *;`? The result is the same. Does this mean that `DFS` is the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default relationship traversal algorithm in Memgraph is DFS (Depth First Search). This means that if you run:

```
MATCH (x {id: 587})-[edge_list:Type *..10]-(y {id: 963}) RETURN *;
```

the DFS will be run under the hood.