# Variable expand by default is using DFS, wouldn't it be better if a user code explicitly specify?

Tags: memgraphdb

Inside Memgraph, variable expand by default is using DFS, wouldn't it be better if a user code explicitly specify what's the expansions policy? I've found the following example `MATCH (x {id: 587})-[edge_list:Type *dfs..10]-(y {id: 963}) RETURN *;` in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579781/whats-the-default-expansion-policy-in-the-variable-expand-case).

Being explicit would make much more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes more sense and it should be like that.  It looks like the issue has already been raised and Memgraph is working on it (https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/377).